# python 3 - a method to store fictional items in a bag list - for text base game

Tags: list, python-3.x, methods, cmd, command

I am trying to code a simple text based game.

So I need a method that can be called with a command such 'bag', and which will display the content of 'bag', a list.

I tried this but to no avail:

```
import cmd

class Game(cmd.Cmd):

    def __init__(self):
        cmd.Cmd.__init__(self)

        global bag
        bag = ['key1','key3']

    def bag(self,item):
        global bag

        print ("your bag contains: ")

        if self.bag.count(2):
            for i in bag:
                print(i)
                print("")
        else:
            print("your bag contains nothing")  

    def look_bag(self, args):
        self.bag('bag')
```

I used the list function 'count' (bag.count(2) just to test. Ideally, I would need a function that would return True if there is any number of items.

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to make the `bag` global? You are creating classes, and the whole point is that things are local to the object.

Comment: good point, I will correct that, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do

```
if bag:
    # there is something in the bag
else:
    # there is nothing in the bag
```

looked at the source code and it says:

```
            func = getattr(self, 'do_' + cmd)
```

So you need to do

```
def do_bag(...):
    ...
```

Comment: thanks, that part works now,  but I what I meant is:   I need to be able to type a command at the prompt, like the word 'bag' and it prints the items or the message "your bag contains nothing"

Comment: yes, I tried that (def do_bag(self, args): self.bag('bag')) and it still does not work, thanks for keep trying

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it:

```
class Game(cmd.Cmd):

    def __init__(self):
        cmd.Cmd.__init__(self)

        global bag
        bag = ['key1','key3']

        self.loc = get_room(1)
        self.look()

    def do_bag(self, line):
        global bag

        print ("your bag contains: ")

        if bag:
            for i in bag:
                print(i)
        else:
            print("your bag contains nothing")
```